# Java Concurrent API's Lock not working as intended

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to synchronize 2 threads using Java Concurrent's lock API. The code basically increments a counter to a certain number using 2 threads but the result i am getting is less than the said number even after using locks.
Code-

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class DemoClass {
    public int count =0;
    public ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public void increment() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            count++;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        DemoClass demoClass = new DemoClass();
        int i=0;
        for(;i<=10000;i++) {
            executor.submit(demoClass::increment);
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        System.out.println( demoClass.count);  // 10000
    }
}
```

Not sure what is it i am doing wrong here.

Comment: "// 10000" Note that the correct result is 10001, because you used `<=10000`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes, you're right. The answer should be 10001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not waiting for all the threads to complete. `executor.shutdown()` just stops `executor` accepting new work.

You need to use `executor.awaitTermination(...)` after `executor.shutdown();`.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/im8BVB)

Also, you should surround the read of `demoClass.count` with a lock/unlock pair, in order to establish the happens-before relationship between the writes to the variable in the thread and the read.